# Get non sequential IDs from MySql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, auto-increment

I'm using MySql to keep track of images, each image is assigned an auto increment ID. The ID column should look in theory similar too,

(1,2,3,4,5,6)

Sadly, over the past two years I've been forced to delete rows due to moderation reasons and my ID column looks more along the lines of,

(1,3,4,7)

Is there anyway to get the missing IDs, i.e.:

(2,5,6)

I've search around here and various other forums, but alas I've come up with nothing. The only answer that i've found similar to mine is comparing my ID column to another table's and finding the differences. This is an option, but my main table consists of 25,000 rows so it would be a bit difficult to do.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: give sample data and your wished result .

Comment: @echo_Me He did. The table contains `ID = 1, 3, 4, 7`, he wants `2, 5, 6`, the IDs that are skipped in the sequence.

Comment: @Barmar yes i mean if those ids are comma separated like he mentioned  or they are in every row.

Comment: He said it's an auto-increment ID column.

Comment: Sorry if my example was a bit vague, here's some sample data:    (4800, '', 1, '1367305200', NULL, 0, '20', '0'),
(4802, '', 1, '1367305200', NULL, 0, '16', '0'),

I'd wan to get 4801

Hope that helps!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table

Comment: Shame this question was closed as duplicate to another question that is not a real duplictate. Try using this query: `SELECT ID+1 from images i1 left join images i2 on i1.ID = i2.id+1 where i2.ID is null` This will return only gaps of max 1 missing ID.

Comment: Look at sequences at http://www.artfulsoftware.com/infotree/mysqlquerytree.php

Answer (score 1):

Create temporary table with integer from 1 to 25000. Then do a left/right join on it to find the missing IDs.

Comment: A memory table would be the fastest.

Comment: Can also be done using a sub query to generate the range of numbers. `SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 + 1 AS integers
 FROM
 (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) units
 CROSS JOIN
 (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0) tens`

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS start, MIN(b.id) - 1 AS end
FROM table1 AS a, table1 AS b
WHERE a.id < b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING start < MIN(b.id) ;
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/db2e0c/3)

Comment: Credits : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table