# PHP script memory optimisation

Tags: php

I have a script below which checks through 35000 ID numbers associated with an API from an external website.

The script seems to end prematurely without error, and after looking I think it may be memory related.

For now I can re-run the script a few times and I will eventually get all the information, but I can't do this in the future.

```php
<?php
    /**
     * Widgets Module
     * 
     * This script was designed to run once a week. It downloads item information and resources from divine-pride.net.
     * The information is systematically added to a database that is queried by the index.php in the root folder; this is the file used to pull widget information.
     *
     * PHP version 5
     *
     * @author     Michael McStay <mjm668@gmail.com>
     * @copyright  2014-2015 crmIndexer
     * @version    1.0.0
     * @link       http://crmindexer.org
     */
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    require_once('helper.php');

    $conn = mod_adm_helper::connect_to_db("localhost", "root", "", "mamajamatempname"); // local connection

    if ($conn->connect_error)
    {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("
        SELECT `id` 
        FROM `items`
    ");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($id);
    $list_of_existing_items = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch())
    {
        array_push($list_of_existing_items, $id);
    }

    for ($i = 1; $i <= 35000; $i += 1)
    {
        if(!in_array($i, $list_of_existing_items))
        {
            $obj = file_get_contents("http://www.divine-pride.net/api/database/Item/" . $i . "?apiKey=XYZ123");
            $obj = json_decode($obj);

            if(!is_null($obj))
            {
                mod_adm_helper::add_item($obj->id, $obj->name, $obj->description, $obj->slots, $obj->itemTypeId, $obj->itemSubTypeId, $obj->location, $conn);
                mod_adm_helper::upload_image(file_get_contents("http://static.divine-pride.net/images/items/item/" . $obj->id . ".png"), "item", $obj->id);
                mod_adm_helper::upload_image(file_get_contents("http://static.divine-pride.net/images/items/collection/" . $obj->id . ".png"), "collection", $obj->id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo "#" . $i . " is already a part of the database<br />";
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the add item code:

```
        public static function add_item($id, $name, $description, $slots, $itemtypeid, $itemsubtypeid, $location, $conn)
    {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("
            INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`, `description`, `slots`, `itemtypeid`, `itemsubtypeid`, `location`) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        ");

        $pattern = "/\^([a-fA-F0-9]{6})(.*?)\^([0]{6}|[0]{5}|[0]{4}|[0]{3}|[0]{2}|[0]{1})/";
        $description = preg_replace($pattern, "<span style=\"color:#$1\">$2</span>", str_replace("\r\n", "<br />", $description));

        $stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $id, $name, $description, $slots, $itemtypeid, $itemsubtypeid, $location);
        $stmt->execute();
    }
```

And here is the upload image code:

```
        public static function upload_image($object, $directory, $newfilename)
    {
        file_put_contents("../img/items/" . $directory . "/" . $newfilename . ".png", $object);
        return true;
    }
```

I would appreciate any help finding ways to improve this script for long hauls or to take up less memory, I am very new with scripts that deal with data sets of this scale that aren't already in a database.

Comment: Don't prepare the statement for every insert.... the whole point of prepared statements is that you only need to prepare them once..... it's only the binding and execute that you need to repeat

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.phpc

Comment: @ Mark Ok so set it up else where and make it global?

Comment: `"after looking I think it may be memory related"` Figure out *exactly* why your script isn't finishing. Otherwise you're trying to fix problems that you don't know exist.

Comment: For a start you can skip the for loop by just selecting the unassigned ids: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table

Comment: @ Jonathon the thing is, I have tried, but no errors seem to pop up, the only difference that I notice is that if it runs into a descent amount of null returns does it really not continue.

For example, ID range of 10048~10999 are empty, and it can't seem to pass this without some help by setting a new min for the for loop.

Comment: Prepare it the first time you call add_item() and set it as a class property, then it's available for all other calls to add_item()

Comment: @ Steve, not sure how I can do that exactly, I may be reading your answer incorrectly but, it is at this current stage impossible for me to figure out what APIs are null until I check the actual API with ID#.

@ Mark I will do that immediately, seems like it would help a lot

Comment: As a quick test for defining the prepare only once, you could also define it as static inside of the method. `static $stmt = ...`. It gets defined the first time you call the method and later calls should use the same value. Also, check your apache error logs. On ubuntu/apache they default to `/var/log/apache2/error.log`

Comment: @ Jonathan I will have a look, I will be working on the script later today, so I will try implement a few suggestions here and check the logs; will just require a bit of searching as the server I am using is a little new to me :)

Comment: Nothing is appearing in the error logs, but I switched over to the preparing once and storing it in a class variable. That helps but yeah, my issue is still persisting ^_^;;

Comment: I will leave this open to find out if anyone can help for future reference, but I have decided to slightly change the way the script works; mainly because I think it is more feasible to just setup a big chunk of information and update/add where required afterwards.