# MySQL - get missing IDs with 2 columns

Tags: mysql, select

I have a table like this:

```
  
Code | ID |
 AAA | 1  |
 AAA | 2  |
 AAA | 4  |
 AAA | 5  |
 BBB | 1  |
 BBB | 4  |
 BBB | 5  |
 BBB | 6  |
```

Can the missing "code" and "id" be listed by only using select query?

```
  
Code | ID |
 AAA | 3  |
 BBB | 2  |
 BBB | 3  |
```

I found a half-way solution code in the link below (works with only one column):
[MySQL get missing IDs from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table)
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is very similar, you just need to include the other column in the where clause and group by clause:

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS start, MIN(b.id) - 1 AS end
    FROM testtable AS a, testtable AS b
    WHERE a.id < b.id AND a.code = b.code
    GROUP BY a.code, a.id
    HAVING start < MIN(b.id)
```