# How to find missing number from single column of table using SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

There are 999 rows and they have distinct 0-1000 number with one number missing in it. How to find that number using a SQL query?

Comment: Really 999 columns ??

Comment: Sorry Raws! please forgive for silly mistake

Comment: are you sure you are having 999 columns?? If yes then I think there is a problem in database design..anyways but which DBMS you are using.. is it mysql or sql-server??

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL get missing IDs from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table)

Answer (score 2):

Use something like this:

```
SELECT Min(ID) As firstMissedID
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM std) dt
WHERE rn < ID
```

Comment: The table is 'std' and column name  is 'id' having 9 records with number 3 missing between 0-10 entries. Now please give me specific query.

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this is the best approach but it'll work.

Create a temp table with a column to hold integer values
=@temptbl1

fill the table with values 1 to 1000 then run this query which will return an entry only if it's not contained in your datatable.

```
select value from @temptable1 where value not in (select Othervalue from othertable)
```

the select statement will return all missing values.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that number column will have only numbers from 0 to 1000.

```
declare @minnumber int 
declare @missingnumber int

select @minnumber=min(number) from Test

if(@minnumber=0)
begin
    --500500 is the sum of 1 to 1000 number
    select @missingnumber=500500-sum(number) from Test
end
else
begin
    set @missingnumber=0
end
```

Comment: Ingenious. Got my vote. But what if OP assumption is wrong. Then so is approach.

Comment: Neat solution. But works only for fixed set of data.

Comment: Thanks :)...But if assumption is going to be true always then there is no problem..I think it will be faster..also we can remove hard coded value of 500500 to sum of n number of values ..without creating any extra table as well as heavy code.

Comment: You know what happens if we assume

Answer (score 0):

Use a `tally table` to get the list of 1000 rows then use `LEFT OUTER JOIN` or `NOT EXISTS` to find the missing Number

```
WITH Tally (n) AS
(
    -- 1000 rows
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) a(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) b(n)
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0)) c(n)
)
SELECT Min(n)
FROM   Tally T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YOURTABLE Y
                    ON T.N = Y.MISSING_NUM_COLUMN
WHERE  Y.MISSING_NUM_COLUMN IS NULL
```

If you want to find the list of missing Numbers then remove the `MIN` operator from the last `select` query.

```
SELECT Missing_Numbers = n 
FROM   Tally T
        LEFT OUTER JOIN YOURTABLE Y
                    ON T.N = Y.MISSING_NUM_COLUMN
WHERE  Y.MISSING_NUM_COLUMN IS NULL
```