# Get missing id from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have `tbl_profilecategory` table structure like this:

```
Id      col1
1       50
3       30
4       40
5       50
8       80
9       90
```

Now I want the missing IDs from table, so the result here should be like this:

```
Id= 2,6,7
```

Comment: So id:s are 1-9? Just create another table with id:s 1-10 and do a not exists query.

Comment: @PresidentCamacho......using sequence 1-10 is not a generalize way......it should be dynamic,where no. can be n

Comment: You want the result in comma separated format?

Comment: SQL can't create new rows, they have to come from some table. You could do this with a stored procedure that has a loop.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this? There's nothing that requires IDs to be sequential, so gaps shouldn't be a concern.

Comment: comma separated does not matter.. i want actual result.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL get missing IDs from table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table)

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```html
SELECT t1.id - 1 AS missing_id
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t2.id = t1.id - 1
WHERE t2.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This will return the result as: `0  2  7`

Comment: This only gets the last ID from each run of missing IDs. That's why it doesn't show `6`.

Comment: yes, good answer, but i am not getting id's before minimum id. means if minimum deleted id is 5, then i am not getting 1,2,3,4

Answer (score 1):

This answer is based [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12325194/2947415)

```
SELECT a.id+1 AS start, MIN(b.id) - 1 AS end
FROM testtable AS a, testtable AS b
WHERE a.id < b.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING start < MIN(b.id)
```