# How to get missing values in row order comma separated?

Tags: mysql

I am facing issue in finding missing auto incremental ids. I am finding missing ids. from the table. Looking for msyql query.

Data format:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5T37V.png

i want result should be like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/klCSb.png

Thanks for the help.

Comment: And what help is needed. Any code we might see in this matter?

Comment: You can generate a numbers table (check here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8349837/2469308) ; LEFT JOIN from this numbers table to your current table and get the gaps where right side table row `is null`

Comment: Could you pelase show me any example?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL get missing IDs from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table)

Comment: Sorry to say, I have checked already this then after i was posting this question. There is no option for comma sperated ids.

Comment: Use GROUP_CONCAT for comma separated IDs.