# How to find interrupted sequence in some column of mySQL DB?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with id(key).

I was generated a lot of rows. 
However some rows where not stored because transactions were not completed.

```
I have total 44000 of rows: first id is 1 & last id is 44045.
```

How could I find ids of 44 absent rows?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL get missing IDs from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table)

Comment: @Stony indeed. it works! thank you for your support!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like below, to get the rows where no other row with an ID less 1 that the ID of the current row exists and where the ID is not the minimum (which cannot have a predecessor).

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat t1
       WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                                FROM elbat t2
                                WHERE t2.id = t1.id - 1)
             AND t1.id <> (SELECT min(t2.id)
                                  FROM elabt t2);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, let me try a solution.

Comment: It also works perfect. Advantage of your solution is fast mySQL response, however it returns next ids from a table. I appreciate your support!