# MySQL/PHP: Finding IDs that are NOT stored in Database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am using a MySQL database with a table containing random records. The only column that is interesting for my use case is a BIGINT column called "ID". This is also the primary key of that table, but it is not an AUTO-INCREMENT column and since this data is fetched from external sources, these IDs are not continuously.

Sample-Data from that Table:

```
[ID]
201101
201504
201641
201755
...
```

I need to find an efficient way to find all the IDs that are NOT yet stored in that database within a specific range. For instance (pseudo):

```
GetUnusedIDs(RangeStart = 201100; RangeEnd = 201600);
  ->  201100
  ->  201102
  ->  201103
  ->  ...
  ->  201503
  ->  201505
  ->  ...
  ->  201600
```

What I did so far was fetching all values within that range into a PHP-Array, then within a FOR-Loop from RangeStart to RangeEnd checking for each number if it is contained in that specific array and if not, adding it to a new array containing only the numbers that don't yet exist in the database.

I think there must be a better (more efficient) way to do this.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Already answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table

Answer (score 0):

You can do this within MySQL by creating the sequential integers in a seed table and checking which don't exist in your main table, be sure to filter the seed table by the minimum and maximum to increase performance, and alter the number of cross joins to fit the range

```
with seed as ( 
    select null as n 
    union all select null
    union all select null
    union all select null
    union all select null
),

numbers as (
    select row_number() OVER ( ORDER BY a.n ) + "YOUR_MIN_ID" n
    from seed a,
    seed b,
    seed c,
    seed d,
    seed e,
    seed f,
    seed g
)

select n from numbers where not exists ( select null from Table where n = ID )
```