# Find integers in range which are not in a set

Tags: c++, stdvector, std-ranges, stdset, set-difference

I need to find all IDs that are not in my table, between the min and max ID. Unfortunately MySQL has no simple way of generating sequences, so I thought it will be easier to do in the application.

IDs in the table are from an external source, and probably around 80% of the min-max range are empty spaces (around 40mln rows in 200mln range). As a primary key, they are already fetched sorted.

The problem is simply `C = A\B`, but the set `A` is somewhat special so I thought of a few ways to implement that:

Generate a `std::set` `A` of all integers between min and max ID and then remove from it the values in set/vector `B`. However I'm not sure if `std::set` will work well at this memory size and with this many removals...

Populate a `std::vector` with `std::set_difference` of vector `A` and vector `B`. However, this will almost double the memory requirements (because of `B` being several times smaller in cardinality than `A`).

As previous, but replace the vector `A` with `std::ranges::views::iota`?

Some custom algorithm, iterating on a range `A`, checking if not exists in `B` and pushing to `C`.

Any other ideas?
What is the best choice (and data structure) for this problem? Ideally minimizing both memory and runtime, or at least with small tradeoffs.
Should I pre-allocate (`reserve`) in any of these solutions?

Comment: Looks like you can do this with just SQL: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table

Comment: @NathanOliver CMIIW but the solutions given there either: 1. only show beginning and end of gaps (so I would have to generate the ranges myself, and at this scarcity it would also fetch almost twice the amount of data than just getting existing keys); 2. show gaps but only 1-wide, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### C++ solution:

You can use the following function -

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>

std::vector<int> findMissingRowIDs(int minID, int maxID, const std::set<int>& B /* B is the set of RowIDs present in the table*/)
{
    std::vector<int> C; // Missing RowIDs
    std::set<int>::iterator it = B.begin();
    
    while(*it<minID) it++;
    
    int i=minID; // assuming min is inclusive
    
    while(i<=maxID) // assuming max is inclusive
    {
        if (it==B.end()) // for i > (last element of B)
        {
            C.push_back(i);
            i++;
        }
        else if (i<*it) // checks if i is not in B
        {
            C.push_back(i);
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            it++;
            i++;
        }
    }
    
    return C;
}
```

The time complexity of the above function is O(maxID-minID) and space complexity is O(maxID-minID).

### MySQL solution:

You can also do it in MySQL, like this -

```
SELECT @minID := 1, @maxID := 15;

WITH RECURSIVE N AS (SELECT @minID AS i UNION ALL SELECT i + 1 FROM N WHERE i <= @maxID)
  SELECT i FROM N WHERE i NOT IN(SELECT rowID FROM TABLE_NAME);
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, however I think it could be improved by manually advancing B's iterator instead of doing full search for every element.

Comment: @herhor67 Nice idea! I have implemented that and changed the time complexity according to that.

Comment: And now it probably does the same thing as `set_difference` with `iota_view` :P
As for the SQL solution... it's unfortunate to manually specify min and max ID. Well, it could be probably changed to `SELECT MIN, MAX INTO...` but I'm not sure about durability of such solution.

Comment: @herhor67 In that case I guess the c++ solution is your only way :) ... Please mark the answer as accepted if it solved your problem

Comment: @herhor67 it does the same thing as `set_difference` with `iota_view` except that it uses less memory, since it does not store all the integers between minID and maxID twice (once in A and once in B & C).

Comment: Well, `iota_view` doesn't store them either... Anyway, turned out that I had additional constraints which I had to deal with in a custom way, but your answer is the best for the original question.

Answer (score 2):

If ID is sorted integer, I think the best practice is calculate length between exist id and id.

result C is vector<pair<int, int>>. first is start ID value and second is lengh.

for example,

range [0, 15] and
B = {1, 3, 9, 13}

```
C = 
{0, 1} -> 0
{2, 1} -> 2
{4, 5} -> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
{10, 3} -> 10, 11, 12
{14, 2} -> 14, 15
```

empty space is {0,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,11,12,14,15}

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void FindMissingValue(int minV, int maxV, vector<int> &B, vector<pair<int, int>> &C) {
    if(B[0] > minV)  C.push_back({minV, B[0]-minV});

    int i;
    for(i=0; i+1<B.size(); i++) {
        const int diff = B[i+1] - B[i];
        if(diff <= 1) continue;
        C.push_back({B[i]+1, diff-1});
    }

    if(B[i-1] < maxV) {
        C.push_back({B[i-1]+1, maxV-B[i-1]});
    }
}

void PrintMissingValue(const vector<pair<int,int>> &C) {
    for(auto [start, leng] : C) {
        for(int i=0; i<leng; i++) {
            cout << start + i << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something? You ask:

> I need to find all IDs that are not in my table, between the min and max ID.
> IDs in the table are from an external source [...] As a primary key, they are already fetched **sorted**.

So, if you consider:

```
B       = 3 8 10 11 13 19 20
beginID = 1  (included)
endID   = 30 (excluded)
```

You should get these lists of missing values:

```
[1,3)
[4,8)
[9,10)
[12,13)
[14,19)
[21,30)
```

It's just a metter of going through the list of IDs and getting these ranges:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <format>
#include <ranges>

auto missing(const std::vector<int>& B, int beginID, int endID)
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> res;
    int cur = beginID;
    for (const auto& x : B) {
        if (cur < x) {
            res.emplace_back(cur, x);
        }
        cur = x + 1;
    }
    if (cur < endID) {
        res.emplace_back(cur, endID);
    }
    return res; 
}

int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v{ 3, 8, 10, 11, 13, 19, 20 };
    auto m = missing(v, 1, 30);
    for (const auto& x : m) {
        std::cout << std::format("[{},{})\n", x.first, x.second);
    }
    std::cout << "\nmissing: ";
    for (const auto& [b, e] : m) {
        for (int i : std::ranges::iota_view{b, e})
            std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:** I just realized that green-21 posted nearly the same solution! Only difference is that he uses `(start, length)` instead of `(begin, end)`. I also assume that `beginID` is lower than the first element of `B` and of `endID`.

[Solution on godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/1n34qGP7q)

Answer (score 0):

I found out there were other constraints (like I had to skip some gaps that were intentional) so I ended up modifying one of the codes from @NathanOliver's [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325132/mysql-get-missing-ids-from-table), which returned me beginnings and ends of gaps, already with proper min and max. Then I just had to iterate over each gap and add its IDs to the total list.

As far as the original question goes, @ArkanilPaul's answer does it probably in the best way, avoiding any unnecessary allocations. Probably very similar to `std::set_difference` with `std::ranges::views::iota` as set `A`.

The other two answers however provide a more clear code, to first compute gaps between existing IDs and then use them to generate final list.